# Segmentation Fault program compiled into shared library but not static

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, static-libraries, static-linking, infiniband

This may be a somewhat meta question as I think my issue stems from a lack of knowledge about shared vs static libraries.

I'm working on a server/client system using infiniband as a learning exercise/prepping for an upcoming work program. Originally I had 2 executables, each of which included some of the same source code, so I split them into common files (being RDMAConnectionManager.cpp and RDMAConnection.cpp along with their headers).

Somewhere along the line I decided I wanted those files to be a library so I can ensure my server and client are using the same lower level code.  I have always used shared libraries, so I went about things as per the norm, creating the shared library via cmake.

THe problem was, as soon as I did this I would get a segmentation fault in a function provided by the library *rdmacm*, specifically with *ib_verbs* functions.  I thought it may have something to do with linking order, but nothing I changed help.

On a whim, I changed it from a SHARED to a STATIC library.  This worked perfectly! My understanding of a static was that it included all the symbols from libraries it links whereas a shared does not.  However, now that I found this vexing problem I feel like I'm missing something.

I have since done some more reading and feel more comfortable with the differences, however I still don't know what lead to this issue (or how to see it coming in the future).  Does anyone have any idea why something like this may occur?

Comment: It did not work perfectly.  You moved stuff around which disguised the segfault, but it is still there.  Shared libs have been around for 50 years.  RDMA has been around for 10.  Your code has been around for 2 days.  What does Occam's Razor tell you?

Comment: Perhaps you can check with `ldd` that you are in fact using the dynamic library you expected to be using.

Answer (score -1):

You should clarify the cause of SegFault, for example run your program with gdb and identify where the segfault occurs.
In many case you may have memory errors, Memory errors are very common problems in native applications and you should avoid them. But may you ask how memory error will show up a SegFault in just some conditions.
The answer is about memory mapping of your program, if change the code (adding or deleting something) or compile it under different compiler or with different switches you may got different memory maps.
For example debug or release builds, or in your situation shared or static build may differ in memory mapping of generated binary file.

So how different memory mapping will cause SegFault? If you have memory problems in you code such as out of bound access, invalid write or invalid read, depending on memory map of your binary it may generate SegFault or not, actually you may have accessed bytes out of the area reserved for buffer but suddenly this out access drops into the another buffer or memory area you reserved and you't don't see no SegFaults (your code still has problems).
With different builds, the order of memory areas or memory mapping may change and this is why you got SegFault in different builds.